Why the sine wave of a sine wave returns a sort of cubic sine wave?
First of all, I'm not a mathematician but a programmer interested in shaders (and thus, applied vector, trigonometric and graph maths) so bear with me.
Recently, trying to create a interpolation of a linear input (from 0 to 1) I found out that a sine of a sine (sin(sin(x)) returns a sort of "cubic" sine.
For example, in a graph, if we input a sine wave function we have a cyclic function that, to me, has a sort of exponential characteristic to it (even though I'm not able to justify it mathematically, it looks like sin(x) is x^2 but cyclic.
Now, I'm aware of the relationship of sine waves and the circle, and in fact, what I was looking for was the wave function of a rounded square, rather than a perfect circle, and I don't understand why sin(sin(x)) gives back that (apparent) wave.
What I am asking is, if sin(x) looks like this:


why sin(sin(x)) looks like this:


Or sin(sin(sin(sin(x)))) looks like this:

Thank you in advance.

One simple observation is that $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{(n)}(x)) = \cos(\sin^{(n-1)}(x)) \cdot \frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{(n-1)}(x))$, and so if say $0 < x < \pi$ so that $0 < \cos(\sin^{(n-1)}(x)) < 1$, this explains why $\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^{(n)}(x)) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, i.e. the graph is becoming flat, like a square wave, as you observe.

I know that this question was migrated from MO, but, even so, I find it surprising that a question with such (rightly!) highly upvoted answers is itself barely breaking even.  Surely the quality of the answers is some indication of the mathematical quality of the question?

The $n$-th iterate of sine (denoted $\sin^{(n)}$) has been studied in great detail by N.G. de Bruijn, Asymptotic Methods in Analysis, pages 157–166. He finds, for $0<x<\pi$, that
$$\sin^{(n)}x=\sqrt{\frac{3}{n}}\biggl(1-\tfrac{3}{10}n^{-1}\ln n+{\cal O}(n^{-1})\biggr),$$
so independent of $x$ to leading order in $n$.
This confirms the finding by Michael Hardy, that the iterated sign normalized by its maximum converges to unity.

I'm not sure you can post images in a comment, so for now I'll put this here. I iterated this composition between five- and six-hundred times and got the graph seen below. Zero is an attractive fixed point of the sine function, although the convergence isn't very fast, so the maximum value after all these iterations has gone down only to about $0.068.$ If you graph $\sin(\sin(\sin(\cdots)))$ divided by its maximum value, will it slowly converge to $\sin(x)/\left|\sin(x)\right|= \pm 1\text{?}$ I haven't thought about that yet other than to pose the question.


Since I know you care for TeXnicalities, you might be interested in the difference between $\sin(x)/\left|\sin(x)\right|$ \sin(x)/\left|\sin(x)\right|, with a noticeable space after the slash, and $\sin(x)/\mathopen|\sin(x)\mathclose|$ \sin(x)/\mathopen|\sin(x)\mathclose| (or, which is probably the same under the hood, \sin(x)/\lvert\sin(x)\rvert).  Of course you don't need the sizing here, but, in circumstances where you do need it, you could get rid of the space (assuming you don't want it!) with $\sin(x)/{\left|\sin(x)\right|}$ \sin(x)/{\left|\sin(x)\right|}.

@LSpice, Thanks for the tip, but is this a bug in TEX engine or convention I didn't realize myself?

@MathArt, re, I can't find the definitions of \left and \right in source2e, and I don't know where math-character default classes are set, but my suspicion is that \left|\right| is behaving with \mathop spacing, and that maybe / is of class \mathpunct (the same thing would happen for $\sin(x)/\cos(x)$ \sin(x)/\cos(x) and for $\sin(x),\cos(x)$ \sin(x),\cos(x), in the latter case probably as desired).
